# Performance of Remote Materialized views in Oracle

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, materialized-views

I have a question reagrding Oracle materialized views ...

We have two databases:

1. Core Database
2. Reporting database

The reporting database has:

- a database link to the Core database
- a number of synonyms to the tables in the Core database
- a number of Materialized views defined on top of those synonyms.

The views are set up to refresh hourly.

With increased data volume in the source system, we are seeing increased CPU to materialize the views.

Upon closer inspection, it appears that the view refresh process constructs the result set within the Reporting database - and sends individual, smaller SQL statetements to the Core database.

Some of these materialized views are very complex, and have lots of joins between tables. This is resulting in millions of little SQL statements against the Core database.

My question is: would it be better to create a corresponding "complex" view in the Core database, and have a materialized view in the Reporting database, as a simple "SELECT * FROM CORE.MY_MAT_VIEW"

thanks for any pointers,

cheers,
Evan

Comment: Is it safe to assume that when you say "complex" you are using it in the same way Oracle does when it talks about complex materialized views, i.e. materialized views that cannot be refreshed incrementally?  Or are you using "complex" in the more generic sense?

Comment: I was meaning complex in a generic sense - as in many tables joined, lots of nested table expressions, group bys, etc. I don't know enough Oracle to know the cirteria which determines whether these could be done incrementally.

Incidentally, further reading has thrown up the "driving_site" hint. I thought that it may be exactly what I need - but I don't think it can be done in a View definition (ie. within DML).

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't have anything too complex in the Core database. You'd put more load on the core database, plus potentially drag a lot more data around.

Have you considered replicating the Core tables to the Reporting environment (simple replication) with the MVs built against those replicated tables.
The SQLs against core should be simpler and data volumes from Core to reporting should be smaller, and the complex MVs are managed in a single database.

Comment: yep. good point. I think that is what we need to do, but in practice it's going to be medium term for us. 
Especially since the transaction volume is not huge. The amount of incremental change to be replicated would be far less than shipping entire result sets periodically.

For now, I was after a "quick win". hopefully :-)

Comment: +1 - this is usually the best architecture if your materialized views are complex (and I'm using complex to mean expensive SQL in this context).  Use simple incremental MV's to get the tables over to the reporting database with little or no transformation and then have the more expensive MV refreshes execute in the reporting database from those tables.

Answer (score 0):

If your transaction rate is not great as you say, I would look into decreasing your refresh rate.  Many reporting systems use a 24 hour turn-around time for reporting services and the users are usually able to adjust.  You could even see significant improvement by using a refresh rate somewhere between 1 hour and 24 hours.